# wrk tests for content stream (octet-stream, image/tiff)

Tags: lua, streaming, load-testing, wrk

Is there an option of `wrk` load-test tool to test routes which stream content to or from server, e.g. streaming files or bytes?

Now I do

```lua
# load.lua
wrk.headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "application/octet-stream"
request = function()

    url_path = {...compose_my_path...}
    
    return wrk.format("GET", url_path)
end
```

and

```bash
$ docker run --rm --network=host --env ROUTE={route} -v `pwd`:/data williamyeh/wrk -t4 -c{conn} -d{dur}s --latency --timeout {tout}s -s load.lua http://my_server:port"
```

Although in Graphana I see 200 responses for requests, in wrk results there are 100% read errors.

```
Running 1m test @ http://my_server:port
  4 threads and 600 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     0.00us    0.00us   0.00us    -nan%
    Req/Sec     0.00      0.00     0.00      -nan%
  Latency Distribution
     50%    0.00us
     75%    0.00us
     90%    0.00us
     99%    0.00us
  0 requests in 1.00m, 14.35MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 48530, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:      0.00
Transfer/sec:    244.75KB
```

And, as a plus to streaming GET method, I'd like to test PUT method, which shall also stream data to server.
Is there any option for this?
Thank you!